# How to Fix Form elements do not have associated labels in Wordpress Search Form (without button)

Tags: search, forms

Is there any way to fix the "Form elements do not have associated labels" issue in WordPress search form without having the search button.

Google Light House Audit:

> Form elements do not have associated labels. Labels ensure that form
> controls are announced properly by assistive technologies, like screen
> readers. Failing Elements input

```
<input type="text" value="Search" name="s" id="psf" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}">
```

I want to add a label in the form w/o displaying the search button?

I'm using this code in my Wordpress website to display search form:

```
<div id="psform"> 
<?php $search_text = "Search"; ?> 
<form method="get" id="searchform"  
action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/"> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>"  
name="s" id="psf"  
onblur="if (this.value == '')  
{this.value = '<?php echo $search_text; ?>';}"  
onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo $search_text; ?>')  
{this.value = '';}" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="searchsubmit" /> 
</form> </div>
```

Code can be found at https://tumrai.com/WordPress_Search_Form_without_Search_Button

Comment: Please reformat your code, do not put everything in one line. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a WordPress issue, this looks like a generic HTML problem ( an issue with your themes HTML? ). Also your code is super difficult to read when it's all on a single line. Break it up into several lines so it can be read

Comment: Anyone here to help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<label>` tag before `<input>` like this.

```
<label>Email Adress:
    <input type="text">
</label>
```

This is a simple method to do this. You can simply omit the use of the submit button if you don't need it to show.

Here is the modified code of yours.

```
<div id="psform"> 
    <?php $search_text = "Search"; ?> 
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"> 
        <label>Email Adress:
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>" name="s" /> 
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to add a title to the search form, you can use any heading tag. If you need any other help, please don't hesitate to ask.